# How do I ensure docker is running the new code in my containers when starting up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am currently writing a webapp - java backend, react front end and have been deploying via a docker compose file. I've made changes and when I try to run them via yarn build for my front end server and starting my back end server with maven, the changes appear. However, when running with docker, the changes aren't there.

I've been using the **docker compose up** and **docker compose down** commands and I even run **docker system prune -a** after stopping my docker containers via the docker compose down command but my new changes aren't showing. I'd appreciate any guidance on what I'm doing wrong to help show my changes.

I also have docker desktop and have manually gone and deleted all of the volumes, containers and images so that they have to be regenerated. Running the build commands to specify ignoring cache didn't help either.

I also deleted the .m2 folder so that this gets generated (my understanding is that this is the cache store for the backend). My changes are mainly on the front end but since my front end container depends on this, I thought regenerating the back-end container may have a knock on effect that may help.

I would greatly appreciate any help, please do let me know if there's anything else to help with context. The changes involve removing a search bar and some text, both of which are commented out in the code but still appear whilst I also add another button which doesn't show up.

My docker compose file is below as follows:

```
services:
  mysqldb:
#    image: mysql:5.7
    build: ./Database
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
    ports:
      - $MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend

  app_backend:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build: ./
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - $SPRING_LOCAL_PORT:$SPRING_DOCKER_PORT
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
        "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT/$MYSQLDB_DATABASE?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC",
        "spring.datasource.username" : "$MYSQLDB_USER",
        "spring.datasource.password" : "$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD",
        "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
      }'
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend

  app_frontend:
    depends_on:
      - app_backend
    build:
      ../MyProjectFrontEnd
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - frontend

volumes:
  db:

networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
```

Since the issue is on the front end, I've also attached the dockerfile for the front end below:

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine AS react-build
WORKDIR /MyProjectFrontEnd
RUN yarn cache clean
RUN yarn install
COPY . ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build

# Stage 2 - the production environment
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY /build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**Update - the cache in the browser was storing some (rookie error) however, not all the changes are still being loaded**

Comment: Run docker build before compose to rebuild the new image?it should work unless u pointing the wrong location.

Comment: Hi, yes I tried with that but no luck. Its definitely all in the right location though as I see it building and running all the steps in my docker files in order.

Comment: I usually specify an image name in my docker compose file so when i rebuild the image i know which image it is using.

Comment: I've been deleting them all and restarting them all though, so wouldn't that cover all the bases?

Comment: #1 Is the error on backend or frontend? #2 Share us its Dockerfile #3 Try to reproduce the error with some java template like https://github.com/jrichardsz/spring-boot-templates/tree/master/000-hello-world

Comment: Hi, the error is on the front end and I've attached the dockerfile for the front end to the question.

Comment: Hi, posting an update - I'm able to view the latest changes if I run yarn build in my front end app before running docker compose up. This looks like an issue of yarn build being in the wrong place in my docker file so I'm going to explore this after posting some updates. Really appreciated all the advice on this post so far!

Answer (score 0):

If your source code is in the same folder (usually) of your Dockerfile, **you can be sure** that your last source code will be built and deployed. This feature is one of the cornerstones, which is the **base of docker**. If this would be failing, it would be the end of the world.

These kind of errors are not related to the docker core. Usually is something at application level and/or its development:

- Libraries mistake
- Developer mistake
- Functional test mistake
- Load Balancer mistake

### Advice

- docker-compose and windows are for development stage. For deployment on real environments for real users, you should use linux and some tool like Kubernetes.

Comment: To provide any info that may help, I think going through your list, I'm quite confident of the developer change as its very simple (removing a couple lines for a component) and I can also see the changes working correctly when running the front end server via yarn. There is currently no load balancer or relevant functional test so the last thing would be the library. The other component I added builds on the Route component in react to create a custom protected route component but even then the normal Route components works. I also have text still appearing which no longer exists in my code.

Comment: In these rare cases, there is on one and absolute solution: compare both builds. Generate the build/bundle.js in your windows /build folder (react). Then perform a manually build `docker build ...`, then `docker run` or with your docker-compose, enter to the live container with `docker exec -it myweb bash`, go to  the build folder and extract the bundle.js. With both builds in your local, try to compare it. Also react use webpack to generate the build. There is a parameter to not obfuscate or minify the build. This will help you in the comparation